# QTableWidget の垂直スクロールバーを左に表示したい。

Tags: qt5, qt-creator

QTableWidget の垂直スクロールバーを左に表示したいのですが、スマートにできる方法はないでしょうか? ビルトインでできないことは知っています。
そうしたい理由は、次のようなシーンがあるからです。
固定小数点の数値を右詰に表示して、縦に並べて配置している上下のウィジット(QLabelなど)で表示している数値と、桁あわせをして大きさを比較したい。QTableWidgetのリストの長さにより、スクロールバーが消えたり現れたりすると、右詰めに表示した数値の水平位置が変化していしまいとても不細工です。左にスクロールバーがあれば、この問題を避けることができます。
なお、QtDesignerを使用してUIを作成しています。QMLは使用していません。コードはC++で使用しているQtのバージョンは 5.9です。

Comment: こちら [How-to move vertical scrollbar on left side of ScrollView?](https://forum.qt.io/topic/89123) では実装は右端がアンカーなので自分自身のスクロールバー部品を作りましょう、となっています。一方これら [scrollbar on left side of qtextedit](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/11878), [Scrollbar on the left](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/23624) では何だか出来ていそうな感じでコメントが付いています。どれもQTableWidgetは出てこないので適用可能か不明ですが、参考に。

Answer (score 1):

スクロールバーを左に表示させる回答ではありませんが、
`QTableWidget`(厳密には親クラスの`QAbstractScrollArea`)のプロパティ「`verticalScrollBarPolicy`」の値を「`ScrollBarAlwaysOn`」にすることで、リストの長さによらずスクロールバーが表示されるようになるので、用途に耐えられるかと思います。